# One-Page WordPress Template

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages

I have created four custom PHP file pages

```
 page-about.php
 page-services.php
 page-portfolio.php
 page-contact.php
```

I have entered custom php code for every page that will show up on the homepage as a one-page site that has sections (section 1, section 2, section 3, section 4, section 5).

When every you click on the top navigation links where the Home, About, Services, Portfolio, Contact going to scroll down to each section on the page rather than going to each individual pages.

Below is the code I entered for the front-page.php and I was attempting to try a code that I find on stackoverflow.com that might help me solve my problem. But when every try the code for first time nothing has changed on front-page also him still learning Wordpress and PHP.

Example what him trying to with my Wordpress Theme Site http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Parallax%20One

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php           
                    $args = array (
                        'post_type'              => 'page',
                        'post_parent'            => '29',
                        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
                        'order'                  => 'ASC',
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );


                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

                            $query->the_post();
                            $tn = get_page_template_slug( $post_id );
                            $word = array("page-", ".php",' ');
                            $template = str_replace($word,'',$tn);

                            get_template_part('page', $template);
                        }

                    } else {

                    }  

                    wp_reset_postdata();    

            ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

[image]

Comment: "not working" is a bit too vague for anyone to help you, maybe you need to add more information.

Comment: @majick You have an Skype where I can explain in a Skype call little much better and also do a screen share of the code.

Comment: the code is there, just not the question. if you can explain it better, you can do so in your question too. https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: @majick I have fix the question and explain little bit so people can understand what trying to do on first Wordpress Theme.

Comment: When you say `nothing happened on front-page` you mean that nothing has changed? You have a front-page set in `Settings -> Reading` and are sure that it is attempting to pull this template? Have you verified that the children under Post Parent `29` have the slugs `about` or `services`?

Comment: What is the exact problem or question you would like answered?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes I mean nothing has change. sorry I have want to Setting Reading and change number to 29 but nothing has changed on the site. How do I check and see what Post Parent Number for those pages on wordpress

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Can we do a google hangout or Skype so I can share screen and explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this theme... Try it out it's a free theme and same as per your requirement. It's a one page website theme available on wordpress.org.

https://wordpress.org/themes/one-page/

Check out the demo here

https://wp-themes.com/one-page/

Comment: Does not Solve my question but thank you for help me.

Comment: It's not exactly a one page site.